# Visual Studio Code, ReStructurdText extension can't find Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, restructuredtext

I'm trying to use the LeXtudio ReDtructuredText extension for Visual Studio Code. It's not working, and the reason is not clear.

After I installed the extension I tried to use it by clicking the "split screen" icon below the menu bar, and I got a popup message that said, "Please review Python installation on this machine before using this extension."

I clicked the "Learn more" link and learned that the extension depends on Python 3.5 or later. My system runs Python 2.7 because our production environment uses tools that depend on it, but I have Python 3.8 installed too. I followed a "learn more" suggestion and added python.pythonPath to the VS Code settings file. Then I tried again, and got the same message.

Did I modify the settings file right? I think so; here's how it looks so others can check. (Line 2 has been added.)

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true
}
```

Did I put the right value in the string? I think so; when I examine C:\Program Files\Python38\ in File Explorer I see that it's a Python installation's top level directory, and python.exe is in it.

Did I modify the right file? I did; when I changed "breadcrumbs.enabled" from true to false, the editor's breadcrumb display disappeared instantly -- I didn't even have to restart the editor.

Any ideas?

The extension instructions also recommend using Microsoft's Python extension to change the setting. It says that this "really makes configuring Python environment easier," although it doesn't explain how.

It says, "Once you have that Python extension installed, open `conf.py` in VSCode." It's not clear what this is for, since the settings file is named `settings.json`, but I hoped that when I opened the file that would become clear. But the instructions don't say where this file is, and I can't find it. I searched my user directory and both Program Files directories, and the only files I found with the name `conf.py` were in Sphinx projects... not a likely place to put VS Code settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Comment: according to the [docs](https://docs.restructuredtext.net/articles/prerequisites.html) you need Sphinx and that uses `conf.py`

Comment: I added to the project's conf.py: `python.pythonPath = u'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\'``. That made no difference. Perhaps I misunderstood your reply -- I don't see how this could possibly help, because there's no way the editor, looking at the file, can tell what project it is in.

Comment: I tried to build the project today and found that with this line inserted it just gets a runtime error: "NameError: name 'python' is not defined."